# Check if css class exist and can be applied

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am using [lipis flag icon set](https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css), and angularjs. 
I want to check whether a given flag exist is the css.
What is the best approach to this?

Right now I am just applying the class and if the flag does not exist,
then nothing is shown.

```
 <i class="flag-icon" ng-class="'flag-icon-' + dialog.model.item.code | lowercase"></i>
```

I would however like to show some text like "No flag" if the class does not exist in css. To do this I need some way to check whether the given flag-icon-xx exists or not, but how do I do this?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703404/how-to-test-for-existence-of-css-class-in-javascript-without-jquery

Comment: @Heru-Luin that's a pretty terrible accepted answer.

Comment: `console.log(document.styleSheets);` may help you :)

Answer (score 6):

## Pure CSS Solution for Font-Based Icons

***Edit:*** Looks like the icon set you're using is background-based, so please see the second part of my answer for a potential solution. I'll keep this part here for future readers.

If you're using a font-based icon set you can do this with pure CSS relatively easily. Simply have a base selector which applies the text "No flag" to either the `::before` or `::after` pseudo-element (depending on which the font-based icon set uses itself):

```css
.flag-icon::before {
    content: 'No flag';
}
```

As long as our other font-based icons are declared after this declaration or have higher specificity, their own `content` property will override this.

### Example

```css
.flag-icon::before {
  content: 'No flag';
}

.flag-icon-star::before {
  content: '★'
}
```

```html
<h3>Working Icon</h3>
<i class="flag-icon flag-icon-star"></i>

<h3>Default Text</h3>
<i class="flag-icon flag-icon-null"></i>
```

## Pure CSS Solution for Image-Based Icons

If it isn't a font-based icon set you're using, you can still apply a similar approach to background-based icon sets. For this, we still the same `::before` or `::after` pseudo-element as we've used above, but override this completely on valid icon classes:

```css
.flag-icon::before {
    content: 'No flag';
}

.flag-icon-1::before,
.flag-icon-2::before,
... {
    content: '';
}
```

### Example

```css
.flag-icon::before {
  content: 'No flag';
}

.flag-icon-star::before {
  content: '';
}

.flag-icon-star {  
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/yiJrwe0.png) no-repeat;
  display: block;
  height: 131px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Working Icon</h3>
<i class="flag-icon flag-icon-star"></i>

<h3>Default Text</h3>
<i class="flag-icon flag-icon-null"></i>
```

Comment: Hi James, it is showing both the flag and the "No flag" text now, any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Ahh, so I would need to add .flag-icon-xx::before {content: ' ';} to all the valid flags? Since I would still like to use the lipis project, this is not a very suitable solution.
The images are, as far as I can tell, set as background image.